# Android: Failed to ensure directory when getExternalFilesDir(null)

Tags: android, android-file

As shown in the title, when I called the method `getExternalFilesDir(null)`, i got a warning like this:
`Failed to ensure directory: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxx.app/files`

So, it turns out that the i cannot get the path `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxx.app/files`
**Also, the problem only happens sometimes.**

Comment: Hey, did you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when uninstalling the app and reinstalling it. But probably the resources of the app (*com.xxxx.app* in your case) had a reference not released.

The solution was quite simple: just stop and relaunch the emulator, or reboot the phone should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are connected to your development machine, and cannot write to the emulated storage on it.

Comment: And how do you fix that ?